# "Denn auch" vs "Dann auch"

Tags: difference, particle

Im folgenden Satz wird "denn auch" verwendet, statt "dann auch". Das habe ich schon des-öfteren gelesen, verstehe aber den genauen Grund für die Verwendung von "denn" statt "dann" nicht. "Denn" kenne ich nur aus dem Zusammenhang von Begründungen wie zum Beispiel "Der Zug ist kaputt, denn es gab ein Unglück".

> Doch bleibt die letzte Verantwortung beim Menschen, der die Technik in Sondersituationen außer Kraft setzen kann. Muschweck meinte **denn auch**: "Im Störungsfall wird von einem Fahrdienstleiter ganz schön was verlangt." Den Fahrdienstleiter von Bad Aibling dürfte dies kaum trösten.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es hier um ein Zeitadverbial handelt, wie es mit "dann" wäre, sondern eher um ein Partikel, das auch weggelassen sein könnte.Vergleich die Verwendung in "Wie meinst du *denn*?

> Muschweck meinte auch: : "Im Störungsfall wird [....]

Geht genau so gut, ohne dass die Bedeutung sich verändert

Answer (score 2):

*denn* in this example is a particle. It could be left out. However to my ear it slightly changes the logical structure as it connects the second sentence ( *Muschweck meinte denn auch...*) with the first sentence (*Doch bleibt die letzte Verantwortung...*). Particularly it presents the quote *"Im Störungsfall wird von einem Fahrdienstleiter ganz schön was verlangt."*, as supportive statement for the first sentence.

Another way to make this connection could be: *Muschweck meinte auch dazu...*

Without *denn*, this connection is much weaker and basically only exists because these are two sentences next to each other. In fact, if I read: "Muschweck meinte auch..." I would expect to find another statement by Muschweck earlier in the text and would not necessarily think that his statement has anything to do with the first sentence. For instance "Muschweck meinte auch..." could as well introduce a new thought or new topic.

Comment: Warum gibst du in einem Deutsch-Forum, auf eine Frage, die in Deutsch über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache gestellt wurde, eine Antwort in einer Fremdsprache? Dein Deutsch ist gut genug um die Frage zu verstehen, und gut genug, um die richtige Antwort zu kennen. Alle, die diese Deutsch-Forum besuchen, können zumindest ein bisschen deutsch (sonst wären sie nicht hier). Aber nicht alle die hier sind können Englisch. Bitte lies auch: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1050/1487